# Run stops at sort. I don't know why it stops

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart

code

```
response = await http.get(url);
if(response.statusCode == 200) {
  var dataJson = response.body;
  var matchData = json.decode(dataJson);

  matchData.sort(compareNatural); //Stop here
}
```

I'm asking because I can't find it even if I search it.

I want to know why it stops and how to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: What's compare natural?

Comment: @KaushikChandru Presumably [`compareNatural`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/compareNatural.html) from `package:collection`.

Comment: Exactly what does "stops" mean?  Does your application freeze?  Does it terminate?  Do you have some bare `catch (e)` handler somewhere that is swallowing all exceptions and errors?  What are the contents of `matchData`?

Comment: Assuming compareNatural as per @jamesdlin what are you trying to do after sorting? What does stop mean in your question? Please elaborate. Please add error logs also if any.

Comment: The error log does not appear. It just doesn't proceed after that comment.
I think "freeze" means more accurately

Comment: Please answer my other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure matchData is a List?

If it is a List, try toList().

```
matchData.toList().sort(compareNatural);
```

If it still doesn't work, then I think matchData is a Map.